# JSP - commandbutton action to find method

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, action, commandbutton

im new in using java. here's my problem.

```
<h:commandButton action="/j_acegi_login" styleClass="Button" value="Login" />
```

for above code, i dont know where to find "j_acegi_login". the way action works is it call "j_acegi_login" within the page or in other files? I searched in all files and in the same page as well. But couldnt find it. is it method or what? please ask if dont understand my question. Thank you.